# Preserve Selected item in Listview, Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Listview with 3 List Items, I need to select an item then it should be stays as selected,if click on another the previous selected item should be unselcted, and also change the Container color,but the problem is it's throws errror like this

Error:

```
The getter 'isSelected' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'isSelected'.
        color: physical_status[index].isSelected ? Colors.red[100] : Colors.white,
```

Code For Listview

```
 final List<String> physical_status = <String>['0', '1', '2'];
    bool isSelected = false;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
     SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 110,
                            width: size.width,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      print("clicked");
                                      setState(() {
                                        physical_status[index].isSelected = true;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      color: physical_status[index].isSelected ? Colors.red[100] : Colors.white,
                                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                        image: new DecorationImage(
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            image: AssetImage(
                                                "assets/images/user_avatar.png")),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

    }
```

Comment: what is physical_status ? add all the code related to this. check isSelected's data type may be String make it bool.

Comment: i have updated the question, isSelected it is already set to boolean,it's in the code @VirenVVarasadiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access `isSelectable` property from `physical_status` list element. But elements are strings, and `String` doesn't have such property.

You need to either store `selectedItems` separately, or convert `physical_status` list to a list of objects instead.

I would take the first approach:

```dart
final List<String> physical_status = <String>['0', '1', '2'];
Set<String> physical_status_selected = Set(); 
    bool isSelected = false;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
     SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 110,
                            width: size.width,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      print("clicked");
                                      setState(() {
                                        physical_status_selected.add(physical_status[index]);
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                        color: physical_status_selected.contains(physical_status[index]) ? Colors.red[100] : Colors.white,
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                        image: new DecorationImage(
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            image: AssetImage(
                                                "assets/images/user_avatar.png")),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: @Morbius my answer contains code. What do you want me to explain?

Comment: Sorry man the network is slow,so i didn't see your code at the time of reply @Andrey Gordeev

Comment: it's throws error like this  `type 'List<bool>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' of 'function result` @Andrey Gordeev

Comment: i have got it from the above answer by Viren V Varasadiya ,but thank you for your help manh,it's the same thing you said about it,but got different way of doing @Andrey Gordeev

Answer (score 1):

You can use list of bool instead of String and also manage which item is currently selected using another variable.

Following code will help you more.

```
 final List<bool> physical_status = <bool>[false, false, false];
  int currentSelectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 110,
              width: size.width,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: physical_status.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print("clicked");
                        setState(() {
                          physical_status[currentSelectedIndex] = false;
                          currentSelectedIndex = index;
                          physical_status[index] = true;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          color: physical_status[index]
                              ? Colors.red[100]
                              : Colors.white,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          image: new DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              image: AssetImage("assets/images/user_avatar.png")),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: it's throws error Cannot provide both a color and a decoration
To provide both, use "decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color)". @Viren V Varasadiya

Answer (score 0):

Change `physical_status[index].isSelected` to `isSelected`

Also put `color: isSelected ? Colors.red[100] : Colors.white,` inside `BoxDecoration`

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 110,
                      width: size.width,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                print("clicked");
                                setState(() {
                                  isSelected = true;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                  color:
                                      isSelected ? Colors.red[100] : Colors.white,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  image: new DecorationImage(
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      image: AssetImage(
                                          "assets/images/user_avatar.png")),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

[image]

You may also create a class like this.

```
class Item {
  final String physical_status;
  final bool isSelected;

  Item({this.physical_status, this.isSelected});
}

List<Item> itemList = <Item>[
    Item(
        physical_status: '1',
        isSelected: true),
    Item(
        physical_status: '2',
        isSelected: false),
    Item(
        physical_status: '3',
        isSelected: false),
  ];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help manh appreciate it,but i got it from the above answer@Nick Romero